# Couchbase Document with abnormal metadata

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

We're running Couchbase Server with Sync Gateway in our project. When I query Couchbase, I encounter documents with Metadata below. It has fields `flags` and `expiration` equal to zero.

The problem is, this document is not in the DB yesterday. Is it normal to have a document with metadata like below? Document body has a `lastupdate` field that points to a date last year. It's possible that we deleted it before, but it reappears now.

When I check couchbase and Sync Gateway logs, I didn't encounter any logs belonging to its id.

```
{
  "flags": 0,
  "expiration": 0,
  "id": "SomeIDXXX::YYY",
  "cas": 1669165471522357248,
  "type": "json"
}
```

Comment: are you still looking for an answer for this?  If so, we'll need the versions of Server and SGW you are using.  We'll also need some clarification of the problem.  What about that metadata is unexpected?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it appears that one of mobile apps that syncs data through sync gateway lost the checkpoint data and inserted all the documents on it to couchbase. We set proper authorization channels and purge interval settings to overcome it

Comment: Got it.  Perhaps you should answer your own question so that others can see your solution?